# Selected item in combobox will notadd to textfield?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jcombobox, itemlistener

I have the following code but i keep getting errors.

void is an invalid type for the variable itemStateChanged
This is the error message but when i take void out i get syntax errors.

Can anybody fix the code.

```
final JComboBox combobox = new JComboBox(procedurelist);
combobox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        procedure = (String) combobox.getSelectedItem();

        private void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                if("Focus".equals(e.getItem())) {
                    textField_9.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        }
    }

});
combobox.setBounds(68, 216, 86, 20);
contentPane.add(combobox);
```

Comment: You're trying to define a method within a method, I'm pretty sure that this can't be done...

Comment: Ok. Well where will i declare the 2nd method then to make it work?

Comment: Technically, you don't need it

Comment: Well then the selected item in the combo box will never be added to the textfield if i dont use the method unless there is some other way of adding it to the textfield.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {   //Method declaration
    procedure = (String) combobox.getSelectedItem();

    private void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {  //Another Method declaration
        if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            if("Focus".equals(e.getItem())) {
                textField_9.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Your declaring a method within another method.  Java syntax does not allow this.  If you attempting to monitor the state changes to items within the `ComboBox` use an `ItemListener`

```
final JComboBox combobox = new JComboBox(procedurelist);
combobox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        procedure = (String) combobox.getSelectedItem();
    }
});

combobox.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){

        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                if("Focus".equals(e.getItem())) {
                    textField_9.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: Getting the following error message now : Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from ItemListener?

Comment: Notice `public void itemStateChanged`

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a method within a method, this can't be done.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you don't actually need it...

```
final JComboBox combobox = new JComboBox(procedurelist);
combobox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        procedure = (String) combobox.getSelectedItem();

        if("Focus".equals(procedure)) {
            // Set text??
            textField_9.requestFocusInWindow();
            // Select all..
        }
    }

});
// Bad idea, learn to use layout managers
//combobox.setBounds(68, 216, 86, 20);
contentPane.add(combobox);
```

Comment: +1 textField_9.setText(textField_9.getText()); textField_9.selectAll; textField_9.`requestFocusInWindow()`

Comment: @mKorbel +1 for `requestFocusInWindow`

Comment: I'm very well remember your lessons